# How to format these numbers?

Tags: excel, excel-2007

Take the following examples of current numbers, and how I'd like them formatted:

```
1             001
65            065
651           651
651001        651.001
651001001     651.001.001
```

How can I achieve this? It needs to be a **format** *not* a formula (this will actually be used in an MS Access project in an SQL query, which accepts the same format).

I've tried using `###"."###"."000`, but then it displays extra dots on the first few examples:

```
..001
..065
..651
.651.001
651.001.001
```

Comment: Which language: C/C++/C#/Phyton/Basic/Ruby/Java...?

Comment: Sorry, but this seems to be off topic on stackoverflow! Read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: @Fuex Explain to me the presence of an Excel tag then....

Comment: Some languages have the support for excel documents.

Comment: @Fuex Kindly jog on... the majority of questions in the Excel tag are Excel questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try entering this as a custom format:

```
[>999999]000"."000"."000;[>999]000"."000;000
```

Comment: This is absolutely perfect Doug, thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Interestingly, when this is used in Access as: `SELECT format(sometable.somecolumn, '[>999999]###"."###"."000;[>999]###"."000;000') as formattedcolumn from sometable`, it displays with the extra dots! Replacing the #'s with 0's (per the answer) also displays extra 0's. Oh well, for the question, your answer was perfect. I'll have to think of another way to do this though...

Comment: It's always something!  Good luck.